# Best way to verify an mp3 file with python

Tags: python, audio-processing

I have to detect whether a file is a valid mp3 file. So far, I have found two solutions, including:

1. [this solution](http://peterjc.com/python/verifying-that-an-mp3-file-is-valid-in-python/) from Peter Carroll
2. using `try-catch` expression:

```py
try:
    _ = librosa.get_duration(filename=mp3_file_path)
    return True
except:
    return False
```

Both solutions above work, but may have some drawbacks, the 1st solution seems too complicated while the 2nd solution is too slow(in seconds depending on the length of the audio). So I wonder whether there is a better way to verify an mp3 file with python?

Thanks.

Comment: I think Peter's solution is the way to go. You could improve it a bit I imagine using [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), which could make it more pythonic. Usually binary files are complicated and the code to read them also is, but you shouldn't care about it. You write it once, test all known cases and then never look at it again.

Comment: @JoseA. I think the validation process of both solutions may be the same. The all trying to decode the file as a regular mp3 file until some exception happens. So maybe a faster audio-processing library is one way to go, and also another solution as you mentioned, is to improve Peter's code. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell Peter's code is only reading the first 2 frames of the mp3 file. So it won't look at the whole file and it won't even decode the audio. It just checks that the file format is correct. And it should be fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try eyed3.

```
In [8]: %timeit eyed3.load("some.mp3").info.time_secs                                                    
1.94 ms ± 43.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit eyed3.load("120mb_video.mp4")                                                        
4.43 ms ± 26.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Basically, if eyed3.load returns None, the file is not a valid mp3 file. And it runs in 4.5 ms at average for even a 120mb file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It deletes any file that is not a valid mp3 from the folder thus remaining with only valid mp3.

```
import os



def isMp3Valid(file_path):
    is_valid = False
    f = open(file_path, 'r')
    block = f.read(1024)
    frame_start = block.find(chr(255))
    block_count = 0  # abort after 64k
    while len(block) > 0 and frame_start == -1 and block_count < 64:
        block = f.read(1024)
        frame_start = block.find(chr(255))
        block_count += 1

    if frame_start > -1:
        frame_hdr = block[frame_start:frame_start + 4]
        is_valid = frame_hdr[0] == chr(255)

        mpeg_version = ''
        layer_desc = ''
        uses_crc = False
        bitrate = 0
        sample_rate = 0
        padding = False
        frame_length = 0

        if is_valid:
            is_valid = ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 0xe0 == 0xe0  # validate the rest of the frame_sync bits exist

        if is_valid:
            if ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 0x18 == 0:
                mpeg_version = '2.5'
            elif ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 0x18 == 0x10:
                mpeg_version = '2'
            elif ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 0x18 == 0x18:
                mpeg_version = '1'
            else:
                is_valid = False

        if is_valid:
            if ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 6 == 2:
                layer_desc = 'Layer III'
            elif ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 6 == 4:
                layer_desc = 'Layer II'
            elif ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 6 == 6:
                layer_desc = 'Layer I'
            else:
                is_valid = False

        if is_valid:
            uses_crc = ord(frame_hdr[1]) & 1 == 0

            bitrate_chart = [
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [32, 32, 32, 32, 8],
                [64, 48, 40, 48, 16],
                [96, 56, 48, 56, 24],
                [128, 64, 56, 64, 32],
                [160, 80, 64, 80, 40],
                [192, 96, 80, 96, 40],
                [224, 112, 96, 112, 56],
                [256, 128, 112, 128, 64],
                [288, 160, 128, 144, 80],
                [320, 192, 160, 160, 96],
                [352, 224, 192, 176, 112],
                [384, 256, 224, 192, 128],
                [416, 320, 256, 224, 144],
                [448, 384, 320, 256, 160]]
            bitrate_index = ord(frame_hdr[2]) >> 4
            if bitrate_index == 15:
                is_valid = False
            else:
                bitrate_col = 0
                if mpeg_version == '1':
                    if layer_desc == 'Layer I':
                        bitrate_col = 0
                    elif layer_desc == 'Layer II':
                        bitrate_col = 1
                    else:
                        bitrate_col = 2
                else:
                    if layer_desc == 'Layer I':
                        bitrate_col = 3
                    else:
                        bitrate_col = 4
                bitrate = bitrate_chart[bitrate_index][bitrate_col]
                is_valid = bitrate > 0

        if is_valid:
            sample_rate_chart = [
                [44100, 22050, 11025],
                [48000, 24000, 12000],
                [32000, 16000, 8000]]
            sample_rate_index = (ord(frame_hdr[2]) & 0xc) >> 2
            if sample_rate_index != 3:
                sample_rate_col = 0
                if mpeg_version == '1':
                    sample_rate_col = 0
                elif mpeg_version == '2':
                    sample_rate_col = 1
                else:
                    sample_rate_col = 2
                sample_rate = sample_rate_chart[sample_rate_index][sample_rate_col]
            else:
                is_valid = False

        if is_valid:
            padding = ord(frame_hdr[2]) & 1 == 1

            padding_length = 0
            if layer_desc == 'Layer I':
                if padding:
                    padding_length = 4
                frame_length = (12 * bitrate * 1000 / sample_rate + padding_length) * 4
            else:
                if padding:
                    padding_length = 1
                frame_length = 144 * bitrate * 1000 / sample_rate + padding_length
            is_valid = frame_length > 0

            # Verify the next frame
            if (frame_start + frame_length < len(block)):
                is_valid = block[frame_start + frame_length] == chr(255)
            else:
                offset = (frame_start + frame_length) - len(block)
                block = f.read(1024)
                if len(block) > offset:
                    is_valid = block[offset] == chr(255)
                else:
                    is_valid = False

    f.close()
    return is_valid



#You can remove this part if you don't want the deletion part. Hope it helps
for file, dir, files in os.walk("download"):
    for f in files:
        try:
            if not isMp3Valid("{}/{}".format(file, f)):
                os.remove("{}/{}".format(file, f))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```